# having an error says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, laravel-5

I don't know why but I'm having a problem get the image in the path /public/img/default.png

```
<img src="{{url('/public/img')}}/{{$data[0]->prod_img}}" width="100%">
```

I believe I have the right path but it says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

here's the database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGQYu.png)

Comment: In that case your belief is wrong. But we don't know where you placed your images on your server, nor what values are contained in the variables you've used to construct the image URL, now whether they are the values you expected. So it's a little difficult to tell you what to do differently

Comment: The `prod_img` column is a `blob`. Did you store the path to an image or the image itself in that column?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one

```
<img src="{{url('img/default.png')}}">
```

remove public